# How to implement authentications using Spring Security with JPA RoleBased

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-security

I want to implement in my application Spring Security to approve the display of pages.
I created the User, Role and UserHasRole tables in my database. In the application, I created @Entity downloads connecting the application to the database. With various tutorials I created something preliminary but unfortunately it doesn't work for my case.
I find this from the error in the InteliJ console ERROR IS INCLUDED BELLOW WHOLE CODE. I want to mention that the passwords in the database will be encrypted by Bcrypt
Below I am uploading the codes I created and @Entity

Initially, I will send a database design:[Tables User, Role and User_Has_role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ohoO.png)

Now I will show the created Entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="user_has_role")
public class UserHasRole {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_roli")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id_uhr;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private Role role;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
 + Getters Setters, added_id, modified_id and dates

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_user")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id_user;

    @Column(name = "user_login")
    private String user_login;

    @Column(name = "user_password")
    private String user_password;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private boolean enabled;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String user_name;

    @Column(name = "user_surname")
    private String user_surname;
```

The Role table was created identically to the User table. For each @Entity, I created Reepositories augmented with JpaRepository  in **UserRepository** posiadam

```
Optional<User> findByUserLogin(String user_login);
```

At the very end, I upload 2 files **SecurityService** and **SecurityConfig**

```
@Service
public class SecurityService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserHasRoleRepository userHasRoleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String user_login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUserLogin(user_login)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));

        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = userHasRoleRepository.findAllByUser(user)
                .stream()
                .map(userHasRole -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + userHasRole.getRole().getRole_name()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getUser_login(),
                user.getUser_password(),
                authorities
        );
    }

}
```

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/devices").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/404");


    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
}
```

Errors from InteliJ console:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration.authenticationEventPublisher
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:183) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:427) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:287) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:344) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:115) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:771) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:589) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1305) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1294) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at figra.patryk.validationapp.ValidationAppApplication.main(ValidationAppApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$SecurityFilterChainConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3fee733d]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:483) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:360) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:417) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$1(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:748) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1740) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:680) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:651) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1632) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:532) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:246) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:239) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:229) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:182) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:157) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer$AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3502) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2601) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:465) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer$AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 40 common frames omitted

2023-10-01T17:10:22.149+02:00  WARN 20080 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$SecurityFilterChainConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3fee733d]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:483) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:360) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:417) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$1(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:748) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1740) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:680) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:651) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1632) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:532) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:651) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1302) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:866) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:854) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:841) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:781) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1305) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1294) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at figra.patryk.validationapp.ValidationAppApplication.main(ValidationAppApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer$AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3502) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2601) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:465) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer$AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

**EDIT 1**

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>figra.patryk</groupId>
    <artifactId>ValidationApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ValidationApp</name>
    <description>ValidationApp</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>20</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
        <jakarta-servlet.version>5.0.0</jakarta-servlet.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: we need the full log, not just a little snippet, we need to know what i sleading up to the error and full stack trace

Comment: @Toerktumlare edited

Comment: ClassNotFoundException means you have problems with your dependencies, post your pom.xml

Comment: @Toerktumlare in EDIT 1 I add pom.xml

Comment: Why do you have `spring-security-config` added? And also with a really old version? Remove that fully, there is no reason for having that dependency. Dont you know what the purpose of the spring parent is?

Comment: Im begginer and i try to learn it but im not programmer. I remove spring security config but  still the same errors

Comment: there are several dependencies that i have no idea why you have added, this feels like you have just blindly copy pasted something `spring-cloud-dependencies` should be removed and `javax.servlet-api` should be removed. Saying you are a "beginner" doesn't matter. Before asking on stack overflow you should do proper research and have good knowledge of for instance all the items in your pom.xml etc. Stack overflow is not a forum, if you are a beginner means you just have to do more research. https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5149